# Wolframalpha yields different results of matrix multiplication based on parentheses placement

Tags: matrices, wolfram-alpha

I was trying to multiply some matrices using wolframalpha when I found that the results didn't match up. Specifically, matrix expression like $CX^2C^{-1}$ produced different result than $CXC^{-1}CXC^{-1}$, although these should be the same. I found that this happens because wolframalpha calculates the product differently based on how the parentheses are placed. Here are two examples:

[First expression](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B-1%2C0%7D%7D*%7B%7B2%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%7D%7D*%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B-1%2C0%7D%7D%5E-1%29*%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B-1%2C0%7D%7D*%7B%7B2%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%7D%7D*%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B-1%2C0%7D%7D%5E-1)

```
({{1,1},{-1,0}}*{{2,1},{1,2}}*{{1,1},{-1,0}}^-1)*{{1,1},{-1,0}}*{{2,1},{1,2}}*{{1,1},{-1,0}}^-1
```

[image]

[Second expression:](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B-1%2C0%7D%7D*%7B%7B2%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%7D%7D*%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B-1%2C0%7D%7D%5E-1*%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B-1%2C0%7D%7D*%7B%7B2%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%7D%7D*%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B-1%2C0%7D%7D%5E-1)

```
{{1,1},{-1,0}}*{{2,1},{1,2}}*{{1,1},{-1,0}}^-1*{{1,1},{-1,0}}*{{2,1},{1,2}}*{{1,1},{-1,0}}^-1
```

[image]

Is there an adequate reason for this or is it a bug?

Comment: In the first expression, a dot is missing which could cause the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it was mentioned in a comment, you are missing a dot in the first expression. When you don't use the dot (or use *) Wolfram will compute the product as
$$ (A*B)_{ij} = a_{ij} b_{ij}$$
when you really wanted it to compute
$$(A.B)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik} b_{kj}$$

In the second expression, you always use "*", so you are not computing what you expect.

> Computers don't do what we want, they do what we ask.

Also consider that, even though this does not seem to be a problem for wolframalpha, in Wolfram Mathematica  $\texttt{A^(-1)}$ does not represent the inverse... you must use $\texttt{Inverse[A]}$.

This post was probably a better fit for
http://mathematica.stackexchenge.com

Comment: But the entered expression is $(ABA^{-1})ABA^{-1}$ and "*" is not missing.

Comment: @Peter The "*" is the real problem... If he had put "." everywhere it would be fine. Also, Wolfram does not see the -1 power as the inverse matrix.

Comment: OK, but why did it then work in the first expression although ^(-1) was used as well ?

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure, maybe wolframalpha does not work in exactly the same way as the regular "Wolfram Mathematica". The first expression behaves as expected if the inverse is correctly computed, and considering the distinction between "*" and "."

Comment: Seems that the "*" is the problem and not the ^(-1). Enlightning answer (+1)